# Service locator pattern and DDD

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, service-locator

I have a framework with a DDD data layer which uses the service locator pattern. However, currently I use a global static `ServiceLocator` class which stores all the references. I would like to refactor this into a correct implementation where classes implement the `IServiceProvider` interface and where I remove the global static `ServiceLocator` class.

Now, almost everywhere it isn't issue to extend existing classes with the `IServiceProvider` interface, except for the entity classes. The problem is that I would think it very strange for the entity classes to have to implement `IServiceProvider`, but I do need a way to access a service provider to be able to resolve repositories through my IoC container.

**What would be the best way to implement the service locator pattern without having to implement `IServiceProvider` on my entities?**

Comment: Can you post a link to the pattern you are referring to?

Comment: Google has loads of good results: http://www.google.com/search?q=service%20locator%20design%20pattern. The series at http://stefanoricciardi.com/2009/09/25/service-locator-pattern-in-csharpa-simple-example/ goes into a little bit more detail. What I'm specifically trying to get rid of is the singleton pattern.

Comment: Yes, but that makes zero sense. Nothing in this patterns results in every entity exposing IServiceProvider.

Comment: @Pieter Never heard of a service-*provider* pattern. Only of the service-*locator*. And that's more of an anti-pattern. And the description in your post doesn't fit the service-locator pattern. You post sounds like you totally misunderstood how DI is supposed to work.

Comment: @Pieter: Microsoft has something they call provider pattern. And there is a Service Locator pattern. But I've never heard of a pattern called Service Provider nor a pattern that forces one to use `IServiceProvider` on every entity.

Comment: I argue it is not an anti pattern. Very often IServiceLocator is a pattern. See, there is only so much dependency injection can do - and often it is complex to debug. There are many scenario especially in the server world of extensible applications a service locator is more efficient and elegant. The main problem here is that the OP goes on and creates thousands of service locators without any logical sense.

Comment: The whole point of the question is that I do not want to create thousands of service locators. I clearly state that I do not think it's logical for the entities to become service locators. However, I do need to have a service locator available from my business logic. Suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why the heck would an entity (business object) expose IServiceProvider? It is a business object, not a service. And IServiceProvider is not even for services, it is an IOC mechanism to expose service providers.

if anything, your ORM / business object framework / runtime is a service provider, but not the individual entities.

let me return the question: I dont see any sensible programming concept where entities expose IServiceProvider to start with.

---update

Services only should provide a service locator - and you should have one. You can use thread static variables for those cases where defined threads access elements (name: UI for example - UI elements must be accessed by spec by the UI thread) which breaks the global singleton.

Comment: The reason would be that I have global services (e.g. authorization) that needs to be available everywhere.

Comment: Yes, but those are not entities, those are services. Also tehy would not implement IServiceLocator but would be exposed through a ServiceLocator. You may get away using a dependenciinjector or a different central composition container / service locator (for example per window), but there is no pattern where every entity turns into one.

Comment: But I need them in my business logic. The problem I have is that I need to have a nice way to get access to these services from the business logic.

Answer (score 3):

A Service Locator is best used in combination with an Inversion of Control container such as Unity, Castle Windsor or NInject. See http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Unity%20Adapter&referringTitle=Home&ProjectName=commonservicelocator for an example of a service locator that works with Unity.

And remember that Service Locator can be seen as an antipattern -- it should be used very carefully. It is much better to use constructor or property injection instead. But in cases where the dependencies are very much dependent on the functionality being executed, Service Locator has a place.

Comment: I do use Castle Windsor. However, I don't think feasible to have all dependencies passed through e.g. constructors all the time. I use the service locator pattern specifically for a number of global services, e.g. authorization.

Comment: Ever come to the idea to use a thread static accessor? Or use post composition to have that in a property - I do that all the time (the later).

Comment: @TomTom: I feel that post composition would mean that I'd still be polluting the entities with stuff that doesn't belong to it. I think that a thread static accessor would be the way to go. If you'll update your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: "But in cases where the dependencies are very much dependent on the functionality being executed, Service Locator has a place." You put words on what I've never been able to phrase